# third party linux auditing software

Tags: linux, kernel, audit

Linux has a audit system built-in in its kernel and a user space process called auditd reading the system calls intercepted by the kernel.

Are there alternate solutions to the Linux Audit system ? I need to explore if there are third-party solutions to audit system calls for a product I am building in Linux.

Comment: Can you explain why the kernel audit mechanism isn't working for you?

Comment: I am checking if there are 3rd party solutions,              kernel audit system is good but not very flexible, Audit system rules called file watches don't support regular expressions and directory watches always recursively checks the sub-directories.